# Is there a standard location to store function cache files in Python?

Tags: python, caching, packaging, memoization

I have these scripts that perform a lot of expensive computations. One optimization I do is to evaluate the expensive function on a grid, cache the grid, and interpolate for calls within the grid. It is important that the files be written out to disk so that future sessions can benefit from the cache. When this script was just for my own personal use, I could put the cache wherever. Now that I want to incorporate it into a package for wider distribution, I find that I need to have some way to know where is it kosher to store cache files for a package? Do I just need to make some decisions, or are there some procedures I should follow (e.g. let the user modify the directory at install time, at run-time, etc)?

Edit: this code will also have functions based on interpolating data from other sources. So I will need a place to store those, too, but need to know where it is standard to do so and how to detect where that is on a particular install (something hard coded at install time, or can Python modules detect where they're installed at runtime?). Point being, this location needs to be persistent in a way that I understand temporary directories not to be. Therefore, this would ideally be done inside of the package's directory structure or somewhere in the user's home directory. If in the package's directories, it is acceptable if I have to do shenanigans with permissions to make a directory that the user can modify.

Comment: Have you tried [`tempfile.gettempdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.gettempdir)?

Comment: Note, that the question requires to write those files onto the disk. tempfile.gettempdir returns the memory FS location

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have the same requirements.

It seems like the way to go is storing to `~/.cache/<app name>` (Linux).

For covering different operating systems, getting similar location can be simplified with `platformdirs` ([src](https://github.com/platformdirs/platformdirs), [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/platformdirs/), [conda-forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/platformdirs)), e.g.:

```py
from platformdirs import user_cache_dir
cachedir = user_cache_dir("<app name>", "<app author>")
```

Answer (score 1):

I found some cached files here
C:\Users\User_Name\AppData\Local\pip\cache

It is the folder where pip is installed and cache files/libraries are present.

If you uninstall and reinstall python, then these cached libraries will be used, instead of downloading new ones.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31735751)

Answer (score 0):

I would consider creating a [named temporary file](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) with a prefix that can be recognized by your scripts, so that the file can be reopened in a later session. the file creation would look like:

```
tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(prefix='myApp', delete=False)
```

Otherwise, I would default to the current working directory and provide an option to set a folder at run-time with [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/argparse.html).

Comment: That can work, but my understanding is that there is no guarantee that temporary directories will persist between sessions. Besides, I have some functions that are based on interpolating data sets, and I need to know where to store those data sets, too, so this would probably be in nearly the same place.

Comment: I see. Maybe just provide an option with argparse then?